# restricting input of GET url on htaccess rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess

**My original url is :** `www.site.com/report.cgi?d=2012-05`

**Requested URL:** `www.site.com/report-2012-05.cgi`

**My Htaccess Code:***

```
RewriteRule ^report([^/]*)\.cgi$ /report.php?d=$1 [L]
```

I want to restrict the request parameter to just `XXXX-XX number format` in GET url.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really understand your question, except you want to modify the URL format placing the parameter value in a different position.

The best way to do it is by capturing the query string like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} d=(.*)
```

The value inside the round brackets is the parameter value (2012-05), which can be back referenced with %1. For example:

```
RewriteRule .*  report-%1.cgi [L]
```

Will rewrite the URL with `/report-2012-05.cgi`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `.cgi` from your rewrite rule

For www.site.com/report-xxxx-xx

```
RewriteRule ^report-([^/]*)$ /report.cgi?d=$1 [L]<br>
```

For www.site.com/xxxx-xx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /report.cgi?d=$1 [L]
```